# How can I overwrite the color of the navigation element

Tags: magento2

I just spent two hours looking for the correct variable name to override the color of the navigation active border..

Just prior, at least another two removing the "create an account" button, which of course left a random "or" sitting there.. I had to google how to get rid of that.

Is there a way to do this without going insane?

Comment: Please, add more details about your current issue. Be nice: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that difficult to find design elements, you simply have to approach this problem in a structured manner and understand how design elements are declared in LESS as opposed to their CSS representation.

I just took some random example which sounded similar to yours to demonstrate how I would approach this. Let's say you want to change the active border color and the shadowing of a search result in Magento 2.

First you start by inspecting the element with your CSS inspection tool of choice, I personally still use Firebug, but you may also use the native tools supplied by Firefox, Chrome or even Internet Explorer (Right-click -> Inspect Element) for this. By clicking on an element in your inspect tool, you can see all rules applied to it. For "active" and "hovering" effects you may need to hover over an element until they appear. In my example, you should see that a search result has the following CSS rules applied to it when you hover over it:

[image: CSS]

Now, just searching for something like `.products-grid .product-item-info:hover` will not yield any useful results because it does not correspond to how Magento defines rules in LESS. In this case, I would simply search for `.product-item-info`, which led me to the following result within a few seconds:

[image: Less]

You can see how `&:hover` has been applied to the element using LESS, which will later be compiled to the CSS you can see on the previous screenshot. It also reveals the `@color-gray-light2` and `@product-item__hover__box-shadow` variable. To quickly find where this variable has been defined, you can simply do a CTRL + left mouse button click on it to get to its definition - at least in PHPStorm (which I can highly recommend for this sort of work). From there on you can either overwrite the variable by overwriting the variable in a copy of the file in your theme or by simply swapping out the variable in the .less file for your element.

Long story short: Learn how to use tools like your browser's *Inspect* functionality, use a tool like PHPStorm in order to be able to quickly navigate through the hundreds of possibly relevant files and most importantly: Understand how styles are structured in LESS and how Magento. You can have a look at the [official theming documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html) to see how to properly overwrite native theme files.

Comment: Oh I'm very aware of how CSS works, it's just the inheritance issues I'm struggling with. Thank you for the tip on phpStorm, maybe that will speed things up, I'm using sublime the moment.

I've built my current template inheriting from luma, so I'm finding it really time consuming to actually locate where the variable is coming from.

Is there any reason I can't just completely ignore all these and write styles that override their values?
So far I haven't seen any style editor, admin control that allows you to adjust their values anyway

Comment: ie. it takes like 2 seconds to add the css, border-left: 1px solid #000;

But it takes me hours to find the variable @element-name-conditions-border-left property in all the different inheritance levels and override those specifically

Comment: Well, you do not necessarily need to use these variables, they are basically meant as an easy way of adding continuity to your website design without having to remember specific values (for example, you won't have to remember some color #123456 and instead you can just type the variable name). And like I said, it is usually not difficult to find these variables with a structured approach like the one I described above, just search your LESS files for the most relevant element class /  ID and then you should find relevant rules / mixins.